# Function overloading not working

Tags: c++

I've a problem with c++ function overloading. Here is an example class.

```
class test
{
public:
  const char* data() const
  {
    std::cout << "const char* data() const" << std::endl;
    return data_;
  }

  char* data()
  {
    std::cout << "char* data()" << std::endl;
    return data_;
  }
private:
  char data_[512];
};
```

In my example I've two function calls.

```
test t;
const char *t1 = t.data();
char* t2 = t.data();
```

And my output is `char* data()` twice. Can someone explain me whats going on? Why is `const char* data() const` never been called?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can't overload on the return value

Comment: Overloading doesn't magically occur based on what you do with the result down the line.

Comment: @StoryTeller You can overload on const though AFAIK. I think the problem here is the choice between the two would probably only be affected by the constness of test, or if it was used as a parameter to a function requiring a const parameter (I'm not sure of the latter though).

Comment: @Borgleader, you can overload on the constness of `this`. But the OP was clearly trying to overload on the return value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `t` is not `const`, you get the non-const overload of the method. Note that the constness of the return type does not participate in overload resolution, and you can convert `char*` to `const char*`.

If you were to try this

```
const test t;
const char *t1 = t.data();
```

you would get the `const` overload, and this wouldn't compile:

```
char* t2 = t.data();
```

Answer (score 4):

The `const` version will only be called on a `const` object.

```
const test t;
t.data();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test t;
t.data();
static_cast<const test>(t).data();
```

this will give you the desired results, and you wouldn't need to store it as a temporary as shown in the other answer.

http://ideone.com/XDdacr